# How to get Eastern Standard Time[US] form my local server time in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I am currently working on a project on asp.net 1.1.I have a requirement where I need the timezone to be change to Eastern Standard Time[US]. I have a piece of code in .net 4.5 which seems to help but that is not supported in .net 1.1.

Below is the code for .net 4.5

```
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
```

So could you please help me on this.

Comment: You're kidding, right? .NET Framework 1.1 fell out of even *extended* support about two years ago. It's *beyond* time to have updated.

Answer (score 2):

things were very limited in .NET 1.1 as others have commented you really should not even use that anymore.

back in those days we had to manually adjust time because we did not have the helper TimeZoneInfo class.

```
DateTime utcDt = DateTime.UtcNow();
int easternTimeOffset = -5;
DateTime easternTime = utcDt.AddHours(easternTimeOffset);
```

the problem in this example is that easternTimeOffset is -4 during daylight savings and there was no good way in the framework to determine the current offset to use.
that problem was solved in later versions of .NET with the introduction of TimeZoneInfo class.

So, if you want to do things a better way you should consider updating the app to use a newer supported version of .NET

Answer (score 0):

Really you should upgrade.  You only need .NET 3.5 to use `TimeZoneInfo`.  If you can at least get to .NET 2.0, then you can try [TZ4NET](http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm).   But if you're on 1.1, you have to use code such as the following:

```
public static DateTime GetCurrentEasternTime()
{
    // The current rule for US Eastern Time is:
    //   -5 => -4: 2nd Sunday in March    (2:00 AM Local Time, 7:00 AM UTC)   
    //   -4 => -5: 1st Sunday in November (2:00 AM Local Time, 6:00 AM UTC)

    DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

    DateTime springTransitionUtc = new DateTime(utcNow.Year, 3, 8, 7, 0, 0);
    while (springTransitionUtc.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        springTransitionUtc = springTransitionUtc.AddDays(1);

    DateTime fallTransitionUtc = new DateTime(utcNow.Year, 11, 1, 6, 0, 0);
    while (fallTransitionUtc.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        fallTransitionUtc = fallTransitionUtc.AddDays(1);

    bool isDst = utcNow >= springTransitionUtc && utcNow < fallTransitionUtc;

    int offset = isDst ? -4 : -5;

    DateTime easternNow = utcNow.AddHours(offset);

    return easternNow;
}
```